# How to enable ethernet connection in CLI?

Tags: console, fedora

My last update on Fedora 22 Workstation simply broke my OS, it won't log in, crashing before it.

I want to download and install some new files to fix it. I'm plugging ethernet cable, but I can't connect to Internet.

In **Gnome** it's like wifi, just clicking on `Enable` or something like that
How can I enable ethernet connection in CLI mode (ctrl+alt+f2)?

Comment: What's the output of `ip addr show`

Comment: link/loopback 00:00:00:... all zeroes, inet 127.0.0.1/8 - that's the top.

Comment: Is there any other output? You can post them in your question.

Comment: Okay, I managed to handle my problem without Internet. It's okay now, topic closed.

Answer (score 0):

The **up** flag with interface name (`eth0`) enables a network interface. For example, the following command will activates the `eth0` network interface.

```
sudo ip link set eth0 up
```

Comment: I tried similar command before, and output is the same - "Cannot find device "eth0"".